# Creating a webapp for managing Gmail email signatures for all employees from one place

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, google-workspace

I'm trying to create an application which allows the HR team to manage signatures for all the employees. Right now they use Gsuite to manage all the Gmail accounts of the employees. I'm looking for something which is similar to [Signature Satori](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/signaturesatori_email_signature_manageme/228371523437)

I've tried using Gmail API to access the profile settings of a user and change the email signature of that authorized user. as shown [here]. Using the following code I've changed the signature on my gmail. (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings)

```
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http 
from oauth2client import file,client,tools

import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic'

creds = None
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = 
    client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json',SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow,store)

GMAIL = discovery.build('gmail','v1',http=creds.authorize(Http()))

addresses = 
GMAIL.users().settings().sendAs().list(userId='me')
.execute().get('sendAs',[])
for address in addresses:
    if address['isPrimary']:
        break


print(addresses)
def signature():
    return 'hhello' + str(address['sendAsEmail'])

DATA = {'signature': signature()}

rsp = 
GMAIL.users().settings().sendAs()
.patch(userId='me',sendAsEmail=address['sendAsEmail'],body=DATA)
.execute()
print(f'Primary address signature changed to {rsp['signature']}')
```

I want to do this and provide a template for all the users in the company managed from Gsuite. Any ideas of how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs/update) for this. According to Google's Gmail API Documentation:

> Addresses other than the primary address for the account **can only be
>   updated by service account clients that have been delegated
>   domain-wide authority.**

You can create a service account on the [Google Cloud Platform Console](https://console.developers.google.com/), the steps for setting one up can be found on the G Suite Admin Help pages [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7378726?hl=en).

Once you have set up a service account, you must give it domain-wide delegation access so that you are able to gain access to the user accounts and edit their signatures on their behalf.

You can use the `Users.settings.sendAs.update` method of the Gmail API to update the signatures of each user by using the `signature` parameter of the `Users.settings.sendAs` resource:

```json
{
  "signature": "html-formatted-string"
}
```

You can now connect to the `Users.settings.sendAs.update()` resource, though you need to make sure you authenticate with your service account:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient import errors
from httplib2 import Http
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import base64
from google.oauth2 import service_account

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic']

# This is your credentials file you downloaded from the Platform Console.
credsFile = 'service-key.json' 

def signatureUpdater():
 #...
  emailAddresses = ["Populate", "an", "array", "with", "your", "user", "email", "addresses", "using", "Users: list", "method", "of", "Admin", "SDK", "API"]
  q = {"signature": "The Signature You want your users to have <b>can include some html</b>"}

  for x in emailAddresses:
    response = serviceAccountLogin(x).users().settings().sendAs().update(userId = x, q = q).execute()

def serviceAccountLogin(email):
  credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credsFile, scopes = SCOPES)
  delegatedCreds = credentials.with_subject(email)
  service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials = delegatedCreds)
  return service

def main():
  signatureUpdater()
```

Comment: Hey I followed the steps you mentioned but when I ran your script I got the following error  `
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', '{\n  "error": "unauthorized_client",\n  "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested."\n}')`